# "Main" value in package.json file in Protractor project

Tags: node.js, npm, protractor

I launched the `npm init` command in my Protractor project in order to generate a package.json file.
The default value for the "main" field is "index.js", which makes no sense in my project. Anyway, I left it like that and my `npm install` ran well.
Is the "main" field parameter important in a Protractor project? If so, which file value I put in it, and how will it be used? Thank you.

Comment: basically it's an entry point for your proejct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. `main` is used to distinguish the primary module for an application. It has no purpose in a protractor project. You can safely delete that line from your `package.json`.